# Current directory abbreviation rule in shell prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, working-directory

Sometimes I see that the current working directory in shell prompt is abbreviated and sometimes not.

For example `/usr/bin` will be displayed as `bin$` or `/folder1/folder2` displayed as `folder2$`, in other cases I have seen `/folder1/folder2` displayed as full `/folder1/folder2$`

I am using default terminal settings (I am using Fedora 22 virtual machine for learning, but I also notice this fact in several other tutorial videos using different distro)

Is there any rule?

Comment: You should add what kind of shell your are using and how the prompt is configured in your `.*rc` file.

Comment: Question updated. I am using default terminal settings of Fedora for learning. Also I notice this behavior in other places using Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe depends with what user you are browsing through the directories?

Comment: Could you add the output of: `echo $PS1` ?

Answer (score 15):

Another way to shorten the path, if you use `\w` is with the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` shell variable. A demo:

```
jackman@b7q9bw1:/usr/local/share/doc $ echo "$PS1"
\u@\h:\w \$ 
jackman@b7q9bw1:/usr/local/share/doc $ pwd
/usr/local/share/doc
jackman@b7q9bw1:/usr/local/share/doc $ PROMPT_DIRTRIM=2
jackman@b7q9bw1:.../share/doc $ pwd
/usr/local/share/doc
jackman@b7q9bw1:.../share/doc $
```

Answer (score 7):

What is displayed in the primary prompt is decided by the contents of
the `PS1` variable. Here is an excerpt from the bash documentation:

```
\w     the current working  directory,  with  $HOME  abbreviated
       with  a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM vari‐
       able)
\W     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME
       abbreviated with a tilde
```

This means that if your `PS1` uses `\w`, then the entire path for the
current directory will be printed, whereas `\W` would cause the other
behavior you observed: just the last component is displayed (with an
exception, in both cases, for your home directory).

The default `PS1` on some random Linux-based system I tried was
`[\u@\h \W]\$`, but this varies from system to system.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of what is in your PS1 variable. 
You can check your PS1 variable by executing `echo $PS1`.

If there is a `\w`, you see the full path, if there is a `\W`, you only see the last folder.